# timeout error to azure container instance from redis queue

Tags: python, azure, redis

I have a couple of apps deployed into azure container instances to which I access through flask APIs, now I'm creating a handler to start/stop the containers, E.G.

app1 is in container1, if I get a request to app1 one my workflow is:

```
1) Start the contianer1 from a python subprocess using azure CLI comands 
2) Make the API call to app1
3) Get the result and stop the container
```

Since I can have more than one request at a time I'm handling that process into a function add is feed to redis queue as shown below:

```
def make_call(arg1,arg2,arg3):


    start_container = 'az container start --name mycontainer  --resource-group mygroup'
    subprocess.call([start_container],shell=True)



    data = dict()
    data['query'] = {'query':"query"}
    #### 


    url = "http://api_url"
    resp = requests.post(url,data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers )
    print (resp)
    stop_container = 'az container stop --name mycontainer  --resource-group mygroup'
    subprocess.call([stop_container],shell=True)

    return resp
```

So each time I get a request one task is added to the queue:

```
r = redis.Redis()
q = Queue(connection=r,default_timeout=3600)
task = q.enqueue(make_call,args = (arg1,arg2,arg3),timeout=500)
print (q.jobs)
```

If I make only one call it works fine, and I can see from azure how the container is turned on and off:

[image]

But of course, that is not the purpose of the queue, 
When I add several jobs to the queue the first one works fine but the rest fails:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/luis/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Also, I'm not using kubernetes for this case since I have just a few or services that will be used one or two time a week.

**EDIT: **

I have found the error but not yet how to solve it.
If I remove the line for starting up and stopping the container I works just fine, so the issue seems to be related to the container not been ready when I start making the requests, is the any way to make sure the container is up and running before making the API call?

**Edit2**

Currently I'm creating the containers with using the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) like:

```
az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --cpu 1 --memory 1
```

Is it possible to it from there or do I have to change it all to the YML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure [liveness probe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-liveness-probe) for that when you create the container, so that when it starts it waits for the liveness probe to return success before forwarding traffic to the container.

```
apiVersion: 2018-06-01
location: eastus
name: livenesstest
properties:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    properties:
      image: nginx
      ports: []
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
          - "curl"
          - "http://localhost"
        periodSeconds: 5
  osType: Linux
  restartPolicy: Always
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

something along those lines

Comment: Great! seems to be what I need, just one doubt, can I do it from the CLI? I updated the question with the example of what I' doing now

Comment: please, read the linked article, it answers your question as well

Comment: It does not, my question is if It is necessary to create the ylm or not

Comment: no, your question was: `Can I do it from the CLI` the answer is yes. you can, but you have to use yaml. I dont see [probe settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az-container-create) being exposed in the cli, but you are not creating the container everytime, only starting it, so you need to create it once and reuse it with `az container start\stop`